# Why does my home-made capacitor have an apparent polarity?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, sensor, capsense

### The Problem

I've built some simple capacitors to use as pressure pads on the stairs at home - the aim is to light the stairs up as you go up them - [here it is in action](https://twitter.com/LMcUnderwood/status/941437821306527744). But I'm getting weird readings form them, but only when connected one way round.

### The Hardware

I've built them by sticking a piece of kitchen foil to each side of a piece of card, then sticking a stripped wire to either side. They then attach to a small circuit board via a molex KK connector ("SENSOR"), schematic below.
[image: circuit schematic]

DATA_IN and DATA_OUT ports connect to other similar circuit boards. RA0 outputs data in serial format at 57600 baud. RA2 connects to RA1 of the "downstream" board and allows for the devices to self-enumerate and manage usage of the serial bus.

Power is provided by a battery and data is read through a rasberry pi via an optocoupler - so no electrical connection outside of this system.

### The Firmware

The firmware on the PIC works by first setting RA4 low for a millisecond to drain the capacitor. RA4 then becomes an input and is attached to a comparator which compares against an internal voltage reference (4/5 Vdd).RA5 now goes high, and we start a timer and measure how long it takes for the voltage to reach the reference. When weight is applied to the sensor, the card compresses and the capacitance increases - and takes longer to charge up.

### Results

Most of them work normally, and take about 800 uS to charge up to 4/5 Vdd. But some give really bizarre readings, fluctuating between about 30uS up to 4000uS to charge - and it changes on every single reading. Even weirder, if I take the connector attached to the "SENSOR" header on the board and reverse the polarity of the sensor - it starts working normally.

So in a sense, I have a solution to the problem - reverse the polarity of the sensors - but this is unsatisfactory as I have no idea why these apparently symmetrical sensors should behave so differently depending on which way round they are attached. Why is this happening?

Comment: It could be that "reversing the polarity" is in fact simply fixing an intermittent connection. Might we worth checking your crimps to make sure they are well attached.

Comment: What connections do you have to ground?

Comment: Nothing is connected to ground as in connected to a spike in the earth - Pins 1 in DATA_IN and DATA_OUT are connected to the negative terminals of the battery - and these are connected to a ground plane on the reverse of the circuit board

Comment: Just a guess but do they work fine if the side you stand on is connected to RA4/RA5 but not when connected to negative?

Comment: My guess is you have a big antenna for line frequency E fields and no shielding to 0V or earth gnd. Hence poor design. Try injecting a clock and measure coupling  of signal with load and pressure controlled coupling with band pass filter to reject humm

Comment: Difficult to say! I've only worked out this pattern since the sensors have been installed underneath the carpet. The sensors behave oddly even when there is noone standing on them, and they were doing this before the carpet was laid as well. I din't really pay much attention to orientation as I thought it was obvious that they weren't polarised.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. I did try connecting everything to ground via the raspberry pi - but that seemed to make things worse so I went with the optocoupler and battery power supply. I'm a novice at electronics so am unfamiliar with your terms - do you mean 50Hz noise by "line frequency". How would this cause problems with the sensor attached one way round rather than the other?

Comment: The 50Hz noise will be coming from things like mains cables running near to the sensors or the connecting cabling. As one side of the sensor is "common" this will tend to shield the "signal" side if it's closer to the source of interference. I'm guessing the cables to the sensors aren't shielded?

Comment: What I would recommend is to condition your signal coming from your pressure pad with a couple of logic gates, then send it into a 555 timer one shot circuit to pulse your pic.

Comment: I'd also expect the capacity change by having a human nearby (i.e. like a capacitive touch sensor) to be significant.

Comment: @drtechno  He's doing capacitive sensing - picking up changes in capacitance by measuring the charge time.  Your suggested changes don't fit that concept.

Comment: "I've built them by sticking a piece of kitchen foil to each side of a piece of card, then sticking a stripped wire to either side." You could not expect a good continuos low resistance contact by sticking a wire to kitchen foil made from aluminium. There is always an oxide layer on aluminium foil. You better use copper foil and solder the wire to it. Use three layers of foil, both outer layers connected to ground to shield the inner layer.

Comment: @JRE yes that would work. I think the issue has to do with the lead length. It would be hard to explain the circuit without drawing it, so I'll draw one and post what I'm talking about.

Comment: JAn 2020: Did it work? What fixed it? Was Olin's input the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One plate of your capacitor is picking up interference, probably from the power wiring in your house.  The reason the readings are so erratic is that it depends on what part of the power cycle the reading is taken in.  Only some sensors exhibit this problem because either the capacitor or the wires to it are closer to power wiring than those of the other sensors.

The reason flipping the polarity helps is because the interference is coming from one side of the capacitor.  Tying the plate on that side to ground greatly reduces the coupled noise to the other plate, because the grounded plate is now acting like a shield.

This is a great illustration of why such a naive capacitive sensing algorithms isn't used in real cases.  Capacitance changes are small, and impedances large to make the time constants tractable.  That is just inviting noise pickup.  Without a algorithm that at least tries to cancel noise, there is little hope of reliable operation.

You describe the old time-based cap-sense method, even embodied by peripherals built into some PICs.  However, that does not make it a good idea.  Note that this kind of cap-sense peripheral isn't included much, if at all, in newer parts.

Here is the cap sense method I mostly use:

Always at least try to cancel common mode noise.  Take two readings using opposite polarity or plates or something.  The two opposite low level readings are taken together as one higher level reading.  Ideally, you take these readings often repetitively.  If they are arranged right, common mode noise cancels out after suitably low pass filtering the stream of higher level readings.

Instead of measuring a time constant, measure the change in voltage due to a step.  That is much faster, so the time window when vulnerable to noise is shorter.  It also allows for consecutive measurements to be taken closer in time, helping to reduce common mode noise if each measurement flips something from the previous.  More measurements per time also allow more aggressive low pass filtering, yielding better noise margin.

For my cap sense buttons (non deforming, so a little different problem than yours), I drive the common exitation line, and the line I want to sense, both high.  Switch the sense line to a A/D input, drive the exitation line low, wait just a little longer than the A/D acquisition time, and convert.  Then do the same thing again except both lines start low and the exitiation line gets a high-going step.  By summing how much the first dropped from high and how much the second rose from low, common mode noise is significantly reduced.  Doing this often, switching polarity each time, yields good noise immunity overall after low pass filtering.

In this method I measure coupling to ground, which decreases the coupling from the exitation line.  A positive signal is therefore getting *less* of a overall response.  In the case of cap sense buttons on a PCB, I surround each button with a ground flood.  The finger adds capacitance between the button and the ground flood.  The ground flood also acts as a shield, minimizing noise pickup from elsewhere.

I've got a cap sense demo board where random noise after all processing is about ±1 count just sitting there.  A solid finger touch yields values of about 200-350.  In other words, I get a solid 100:1 signal to noise ratio with this method.

Answer (score 1):

More investigation on my system has shown the answer to this - 50Hz coupling from the mains power lines in the house (as everyone else has said). Every sensor does actually display some variation between samples, and putting all the numbers into a spreadsheet shows a sinusoidal variation, with a period of approximately 1 second. Some sensors have much more variation in one orientation than the other, likely due to their physical orientation towards the source of interference.

Each sample takes about 5ms to process  - and then it waits 250ms until doing the next sample, This gives us a period of 255ms, or 12¾ cycles at 50Hz - which will process through the mains signal every 4 samples (or one second).

I've solved this problem for myself by getting the PIC to monitor the 50Hz ripple and sync the sample with the peak of the ripple. This has lead to rock-steady sensor readings.

Olin's solution is actually much better than this, and I'll implement that next if I run into any problems